# HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I'm having issues deploying .NET Core applications to IIS on a Windows 10 machine.

When I deploy to IIS and navigate to the site I recieve the message:

```
"HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime
Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526
```

In my event viewer, every call to the page generates 3 error messages.

1. > Unable to locate application dependencies. Ensure that the versions of Microsoft.NetCore.App and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App targeted by the application are installed.
2. > Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:
3. > Failed to start application '/LM/W3SVC/4/ROOT', ErrorCode '0x8000ffff'.

On these alone, I'd go down the rabbit hole of thinking there's some issue in the build of the project or perhaps my installation of some .NET Core package except:

1. I have two other .NET Core 3.1 sites running at different ports.  In fact, if I copy the files from the directory of a working site, to the directory of a non-working site they will not run through IIS.  If I copy files from the directory of a non-working site, to a working site, those files will run through IIS.
2. If I click on the executable for any of the sites and navigate to the specified localhost, they open up in a web browser just fine.
3. I can run all manner of framework-dependent and Self-Contained .Net Core 3.1 and .Net Core 5.0 console apps anywhere on the same system.
4. The two sites that do work, showed the same error message the first time I went to publish. I tried adjusting settings, reinstalling runtimes and the like but failed to isolate anything that caused them to start running a few hours after the first attempt at deployment.
5. There is no visibile difference in settings in the Application Pool or the sites themselves between the sites that work and the sites that don't.

I think there must be some issue with how I've configured IIS, the sites, or the application pools, but as best I can tell there isn't any difference.  If anyone has encountered this, I'm all ears for suggestions.

Comment: Could you please share the your IIS web site File structure？How you host the new two application? You have created two new web application?

Comment: The differences are not easy to observe if you are not familiar with IIS. Run reports https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html and see what they say.

Comment: @LexLi -What a great tool you have made!  I was able to quickly run net-core diagnostics and find that the application pools didn't have permissions to the site folders.  Quick and easy fix for many hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: I got this error when neglecting to set "Self-Contained" Deployment Mode when publishing from Visual Studio.

Comment: Where can I find this amazing tool!  The links are all broken.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I just clicked the link above posted by Lex Li and it still works.  Navigating to the get started page has links to download the JexusManager package.

Comment: @VinnieFusca  The link takes you to the description page, but once you're there, the download link is malformed. Here's it is as copied using right-click: http://https//dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Comment: @VinnieFusca I tried to correct the link, but it takes you the general dotnet-core download page.

Comment: @LexLi  Why isn't your tool listed with the other tools: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/

Comment: @ATL_DEV That page only lists what Microsoft itself offers.

Comment: @LexLi  OK.  I thought you made an official tool. Btw, where can get it. The download link is broken.

Comment: @ATL_DEV https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/install.html indicate how can installl the tool and has a link to project github with latest releases

Comment: I had a similar problem: HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime.
After some trouble and search, I found a solution, which was adding of AspNetCoreModuleV2  into the project file. Maybe it could be a solution for your problem also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the tool suggested (and created) by @LexLi I was able to determine the issue was caused by the application pool not having permissions to the site folder.  Giving it permissions fixed the issue.  This was not clear from the error messages.  Answered here in case anyone else experiences the same error message.

Comment: I installed that tool but dont see how to use it. Any help?

Comment: You must run as admin to see your server.  Then there is a "ASP.NET Core Diagnostics " link on the right when you highlight your site in the left tree.  Though I think I got it to work, it got me no closer to figuring out my problem.

Comment: Check @Alex Monkey answer, that solve the problems.

Answer (score 44):

In my case, the target machine was missing the ASP.NET Core runtime itself.

Issue is resolved after installing the **Hosting Bundle** from
[.Net Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)

Comment: or more recently: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: all versions: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet

Answer (score 36):

Similar to [Alex Monkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66234516/5405967), I was missing the hosting bundle.

To be more specific, my problem was that I accidentally installed *just the runtime* instead of the *hosting bundle*.  I assumed the "x64" link in the picture below would download an x64 version of the bundle, but it does not.

**You need to click the words "Hosting Bundle" to get the correct installer:**

[image: download links]

Get the hosting bundle for any version of .NET [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet).

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the Alex Monkey answer?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli You can't tell?  Mine is more specific.  It points out an easy mistake to make due to the confusing appearance of Microsoft's runtime-downloading website.  It also provides a picture and a more general link.

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the same error messages for a new .NET Core 3.1 framework-dependent web app on an IIS server which was already hosting other .NET Core 3.1 framework-dependent web apps with no problem. The messages in Event Viewer were slightly different; but also very hard to find - sometimes I couldn't see any events which seemed to relate.

If I converted the site to stand-alone "win-x86", it worked; but stand-alone "win-x64" didn't work.

After days of...

- Reading the information on the linked Microsoft URL in the error message,
- running the site from the command line (no problem),
- checking `dotnet --info` on the IIS server,
- checking `dotnet --info` on the build server,
- staring at JSON config files, project files, build settings, publish settings and IIS settings

...this turned out to be an AppPool setting.

In the AppPool's Advanced Settings, there is an "Enable 32-Bit Applications" setting, which IIS considers the default to be False; but on mine was True. Toggling this setting caused the site to work and fail, when False and True, respectively.

It had been set to True on my site because we use [octopusdeploy](/questions/tagged/octopusdeploy) to deploy our site, and the "IIS AppPool – Create" step has an option relating to this setting; but in Octopus, the default value is True, so this needed turning off.

Comment: Wow man! beats me how you determined that an app pool setting was the culprit but sure was. It's exactly what you said. It fixed my problem! Thank you so much

Comment: @Tarik.J the clue for me was *"If I converted the site to stand-alone "win-x86", it worked; but stand-alone "win-x64" didn't work."*

Comment: @Richardissimo It didn't work in my case. I am working on the .Net 5.0 project. I have another .Net 5.0 application running on a different port and is working fine. I am currently recreating the build for republishing with setting the Target Runtime option as win-x64 (Previously it was set to portable).

Comment: @Noor did this key part of my answer apply to your situation: `If I converted the site to stand-alone "win-x86", it worked; but stand-alone "win-x64" didn't work.` ?

Comment: This fixed it for my situation for .NET 6.0, same fix.

Answer (score 9):

Even though 99% of the time, it is probably due to a missing or incorrect runtime version of .NET/.NET Core, here is something you can try:

Check that the arguments property of the aspNetCore XML element in your web.config file is pointing to the correct project.dll file (and that the file exists).

In my case, I had a perfectly setup web.config file for one project and tended to just copy that to new projects.

Occasionally, I would forget to change the arguments value in that area and it yielded the error that makes you think its a runtime issue with your dotnet version.

What helped me get there is that it worked with a blank .NET6 project in my shared hosting plan so I knew it was **not** a missing .NET6 runtime issue.

```
<aspNetCore 
    processPath="dotnet" 
    arguments=".\YourProject.dll" 
    stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
    stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess"
>
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable 
            name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" 
            value="Development" 
        />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

HERE: arguments=".\YourProject.dll"

Comment: I wish i had stumpled upon your answer instead of wasting 5 whole days on this stupid error message. It's impossible to guess that the path the DLL is wrong when the error says nothing about it.

Comment: It helps to know that the `arguments` field also accepts absolute paths, e.g., `arguments="D:\Code\MyApp\MyApp.dll"`. Useful when troubleshooting and you want to rule out relative base path issues.

Comment: Making sure the stdoutLogFile attribute is set, it will tell you which version of dotnet framework it was looking for. This helped me solve my issue!

Answer (score 6):

My fix was:
in the error it usually says which version of runtime it tried to load, and which versions it found instead.
running `dotnet --info` gives the list of installed .NET runtimes:
[image]

mine was missing 5.0.0.
so I went to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0
and expanded the 5.0.0 and installed the version I needed. solution builds fine now.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem...

my solution is quite simple and sort of embarrassing at the same time :)
I thought asp.net core host bundles are downward compatible.

Solution: my application was configured with 3.1. as target framework but I had installed the 5.0.9 hosting bundle on the iis.

**After I installed the right version of the hosting bundle, the 3.1. version, it worked!**

Answer (score 5):

I got this error because my App needs "**Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App**", I don't know why.
Check the file: MyAppTest.runtimeconfig.json

Show config json file

[image: 1]

but sure, you need to install "Hosting Bundle" (the right version)

Comment: yeah right, I installed Desktop Runtimes and the web app started working!

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had to install both .NET 5 and .NET Core 3.1. Some folks here were suggesting to download 3.1 (my app is targeting 3.1) but when I go to the Microsoft site it "recommends" the latest which at the time of this post is 5.0 (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0).

Well, 5.0 alone causes the (HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime) issue.

I was finally able to fix it AFTER I installed 3.1 as well https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1.

Answer (score 3):

After stumbling upon alot of stuffs related to

- .net hosting bundles
- App Pool Settings and Folder Permission

It was mis-match of project dll name.

- i have renamed the project
- build project
- deployed over local server [it worked as it overwrite web.config file]
- deployed over stagging server [it failed as web.config file was not overwritten and output dll file was different from old one]

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this error by changing Deployment Mode from Framework Dependent to Self Contained during the publishing process. Not sure how this change fixed that, but it works for me. I use .NET 5.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was a symptom in my scenario as well - I just wasn't prepared to accept the solution as being to ship the site as self-contained, due to the additional resources required. It may be worth seeing whether my answer solves your problem.

Comment: This also applies to .NET 6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74346843/5198140

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on production after few days of deployment. Suddenly stopped working with the error (HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime). In my case, I just repaired the installed version and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the IIS server had the required version Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0 and when I ran the dotnet cmd I noticed that it only had Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0 installed.
I found the required version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App on the IIS server by consulting the deps.json file.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20b5e111-11bd-4a9a-85fe-0522112ce84d/need-help-with-resolving-http-error-50031-on-iis?forum=aspdotnetcore

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on production after deployment. Please check all of the dll are deployed on production server. In my case one of the dll was missing. I just upload that dll and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Had this error when i first deployed my new .Net Core 6 app to the IIS. Then I found out I need to switch from framwerok-dependent mode to self-contained, which containes the target .NET runtime.

The problem was gone.

Comment: This answer has [already been given by @Simple83](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68495489/5198140) more than a year prior to this answer being added, the only difference being that his answer cited .NET 5 and this cites .NET 6. This would normally be done by adding a comment to that answer that it also worked on .NET 6, rather than adding a duplicate answer, but I can see that may not have been possible with your reputation. I will add a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue and my fix is similar to the answer above by @Janatbek Orozaly.

I'm now moving a site to another server so in the process of setting up the new server to host the website I came across this issue. I like another user above thought that the latest supported versions of .Net6 or .Net7 where downward compatible, which it is not having following this thread.

Would also like to point out that even the latest version may not be compatible with the targeted framework as well. So I initially tried using 5.0.17 (latest version of .NET5) and was still having the same issue. I was able to resolve this issue by installing the 5.0.4 version. At the time, the website was built using NET 5.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I moved from 2.1 to 6.0

Application deploy was without deleting previously deployed files, so old unused files (.dll) were keeped. Somehow this situation triggered error: 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

After cleaning folder and redeploying app - error had gone.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I needed to install a newer release of .net 6 hosting bundle. I had recreated the project with a higher .net6 release after another error but the server was using an earlier version of .net6 hosting bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

After a long agonizing search my problem was in my .runtimeconfig.json file

For some reason it had "tfm": "net3.1" and "version : "3.1.0". My fix.

```
"runtimeOptions": {
"tfm": "net5.0",
"framework": {
  "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
  "version": "6.0.2"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I attempted to run in VS2022 a github sample I downloaded.
I ran:

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
```

It listed:

```
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Then I right-clicked the solution, properties:
From the Target Framework dropdown: I changed it from 3.1 to 7.0.

That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem after host patching. .Net version was installed and it was present in "*Add or remove programs*" but when checking directory for given version - it was empty:

- `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`
- `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App`

I have **reinstalled .NET updates** and rebooted the server. Problem has gone.

Depends of what part from above is missing, reinstall/repair following:

- `.NET Runtime`
- `ASP.NET Core - Shared Framework`
- `.NET - Windows Server Hosting`

If you are not sure, reinstall all, then restart the host.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped: Start->Add or Remove Programs -> repair for Microsoft .NET 6.0.23 - Windows Server Hosting.

Answer (score 0):

A simple reason this can happen is if your IIS app is pointed to the wrong physical path. I had an app that was pointed here:

> c:\code\myapp\bin\debug\net6.0

Although it may look correct, IIS didn't like it and threw the HTTP 500.31 error. Changing it to the root path resolved it:

> c:\code\myapp

Be sure to stop and restart the app pool after making a change like this to ensure it takes effect.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it helps recycling the Application Pool.