# ASP.NET Core no default page when I publish project to server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, iis, hosting

I am trying to publish a website to my IIS server thats running on a Windows Server 2019. When I publish the site all the files get transfered but in a very weired looking format, theres an .exe file and a lot of .dll files. I am used to .html files. But when I try to get into the website I get all kinds of error codes and by almost a day of research and experiments I've come up with that I dont have a default page. As I have .cshtml pages in my project I dont have any page at all in my published version. There is so much I could upload here so I dont know what to actually upload so just ask in the comments and ill upload everything you need. Thanks beforehand!!!

[Directory of Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwTDw.png)
[Directory of Published Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrES5.png)

Comment: ASP.NET Core applications are console apps, that is why you have an exe file. Your app should have a default route that is served when you hit the root of the site. I think maybe you do not have [.NET Core hosting setup in IIS.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: The `.cshtml` files are compiled, so you won't see these in the published output. They're compiled into the `Business.WebSite.Views.dll` file shown in your screenshot. What do you see when you load your site in the browser? Is it a 404, or something else?

Comment: I get error access forbidden Kirk Larkin. Crowcoder, if I install this will the webiste start working?

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer, but I can say that it will never work if you do not have it installed. On the server you can run `dotnet --list-runtimes` to see if you have the ASP.NET runtime installed for the .NET Core version of your application.

Comment: I installed it and now I get the error "HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime". It says that common soulotions are Microsoft.NetCore.App was not found

Comment: This really isn't a programming question so you might want to use another stackexchange site, but I can say I have seen that before. There are multiple causes so don't hold your breath, but for me it was a bug with .net core 2.2 runtime. If you have a certain version of the 2.2 runtime installed (I forget which) it will blow up everything newer. If you don't have that specific runtime installed then I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, but I changed in the web.config file to AspNetCore instead of V2, now it says you dont have permission to view this page

Comment: From your description, perhaps the issue is relates that the application pool not having permissions to the site folder, try to give the permission, refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317970/). Besides, please check your application version and .net core version, then, refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS (check the Prerequisites and Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle).

Comment: Ok, but sins it became such a problem I figured it would be much easier transfer all the code and repairing it into a html file. Now it works but as html instead of mvc. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved everything to a html file and repaired it, now it runs as html instead of .NET Core