# problem iis - HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I'm develoğing Asp.net Core Mvc App .Net Core 3.1

I am get this error : HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime

I searched this problem many forums. Everybody says, .Net Core not installed. But my hosting provider say "Your package Supported .Net 3.1"

How to fix this problem?

Web.conifg file

```
    add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" 

  aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Book.Web.BackEnd.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess"
```

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report and see what common issue you hit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317970/http-error-500-31-failed-to-load-asp-net-core-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

After a long search my problem was in my .runtimeconfig.json file

For some reason it had "tfm": "net3.1" and "version : "3.1.0". My fix.

```
"runtimeOptions": {
"tfm": "net5.0",
"framework": {
  "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
  "version": "6.0.2"
},
```

Maybe yours has a similar issue.